# Trying to install R script in Docker, but need to get around Country and Timezone questions

Tags: docker, installation

I am trying to install R script into Docker, and am doing it by my script, but it fails because R installation asks for Country (2) and Timezone (37), and putting -y doesn't get around it. I am not a programmer, so kid gloves may be required. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Should include my commands:            cd ..
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
#echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install r-base
#have to manually put in country code (2) and timezone (37)
apt-get install littler

Answer (score 2):

Never mind I found the answer here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes

ENV TZ=America/Chicago
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone